# Session Login LDAP in PHP with Access Credentials

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, session-variables, ldap-query

I am new to PHP and am working on an LDAP login script which will login to the LDAP server using organization credentials, then verify the user's username and password in Active Directory.
There are several good examples, and I've been looking at [this one](https://samjlevy.com/php-ldap-login/), modifying it to suit my particular needs.
My question is this - in my orgainization's old system (in Classic ASP), there were 2 functions:

1. `BindReturnUPN(username,domain)` (this would return the `'userPrincipalName'`)
2. `BindAuthUPN(upn,password)` (this would take the `'userPrincipalName'` from the `BindReturnUPN` function and then return an `error number` and `error description` which would determine whether or not the user was logged in.)

In this PHP example, is there any analogy to the 2 functions used in the Classic ASP system?
I've been thinking that I can use the organization log in credentials 'hard coded' to access the LDAP, then search for the matching username and password (from the form), although I'm not sure how the binding would be checked for them.  Perhaps an inner if/then condition to check the username/password binding, within the outer organization credentials binding check?
This script is working for me, in showing that I get successfully logged on, yet I'm unsure about the binding and how to check username/password against AD.  Thanks for any leads.

Here's my code so far (the `$_SESSION['access']` variable determines whether the user is logged in):

login.php

```
<?php
// initialize session
session_start();

include("authenticate.php");

// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
    // destroy session
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION = array();
    unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
    session_destroy();
}

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){
    // run information through authenticator
    if(authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
    {
        // authentication passed
        header("Location: protected.php");
        die();
    } else {
        // authentication failed
        $error = 1;
    }
}

// output error to user
if(isset($error)) echo "Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights<br />";

// output logout success
if(isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Logout successful";
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="userLogin" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="userPassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

authenticate.php

```
<?php
function authenticate($user, $password) {
    if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;

    // active directory server
    $ldap_host = "server.college.school.edu";


    // active directory DN (base location of ldap search)
    $ldap_dn = "OU=Departments,DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu";


    // active directory user group name
    $ldap_student_group = "ALL-STUDENTS";


    // domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_dom = 'college\web-account';


    $ldap_password = "password_students";


    // connect to active directory
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

    // configure ldap params
    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

    // verify user and password
    //if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_usr_dom, $ldap_password)) {
        // valid
        // check presence in groups
        //$filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
        $filter = "(cn=".$user.")";
        $attr = array("memberof");

        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");

        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);

        // check groups
        $access = 0;
        foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
            // is student group, break loop
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_student_group)) { $access = 2; break; }      

        }

        if($access != 0) {
            // establish session variables
            echo '<br>access'.$access.'<br>';

            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
            return true;
        } else {
            // user has no rights
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // invalid name or password
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

protected.php

```
<?php
// initialize session
session_start();
echo '<br>access'.$_SESSION['access'].'<br>';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    // user is not logged in, do something like redirect to login.php
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
}

if($_SESSION['access'] != 2) {
    // another example...
    // user is logged in but not a student, let's stop him
    die("Access Denied");
}
?>

<p>Welcome <?= $_SESSION['user'] ?>!</p>

<p><strong>Secret Protected Content Here!</strong></p>

<p>Mary Had a Little Lamb</p>

<p><a href="login.php?out=1">Logout</a></p>
```